# MonoDevelop "else if" broken indentation

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop, indentation, auto-indent

I'm using MonoDevelop-Unity 5.9.6.

I have created a custom policy, which mostly works.

There's one problem which despite multiple attempts I haven't been able to fix.

"`else if`" clauses have a completely broken indentation, as shown here:

[broken else if indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUNGf.png)

```
        if ( Input.GetButton( "Left" ) )
        {
            _nextDir = Direction.Left;
        }
        else if ( Input.GetButton( "Right" ) )
            {
                _nextDir = Direction.Right;
            }
            else if ( Input.GetButton( "Up" ) )
                {
                    _nextDir = Direction.Up;
                }
                else if ( Input.GetButton( "Down" ) )
                    {
                        _nextDir = Direction.Down;
                    }
        else
        {
                        ;
        }

        return false;
```

What could be causing it?

I don't think anyone would ever want to indent this way, so I assume it's either a bug or some settings that don't go well together, and if it's the latter, I hope someone will be able to point me out in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but monodevelop just sucks. I've never managed to make it follow a consistent set of formatting rules

Comment: Quoting @Dunno . Use visual studio , then ctrl k+d and voilà auto-indentation

Comment: Monodevelop is ass. Unity uses a customized version, slightly, but the main problem is that MD has issues to begin with. Back in the Unity 3.5 days when I was first starting I found that pasting something would cause the character immediately to the right of my cursor would duplicate. But only in .js files and only on Windows (the Mac version was fine). Reported it as a bug to MD and they're like "we don't use JS so we're not fixing it, also that's a branch of a really old version of MD. Complain to Unity."  Took until Unity 4.5 before they updated to a new version of MD. TLDR: use VS.

Comment: MD is awesome, but Unity is lagging on the adoption of new versions of it, complain to Unity

Comment: @CristianoSoleti there's no Visual Studio on OSX

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/it/vs/visual-studio-mac/

Answer (score 0):

I guess MonoDevelop sees the `else if` statement as an `if` statement embedded in an `else` statement. So, if you have turned off the  **Align Embedded Statements** option in your policy, you'll be getting some weird indentations. Just turn it back on and you'll have your code formatted the way you like it.

Comment: Could have been the answer… but sadly, it's already on :( disabling it doesn't seem to have any effect, so I guess it's just ignoring it?